# Difference between component.get("") and component:find("")

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

what is the difference between component.get("") and component:find("")?

I thought component.get("") was for aura:attribute and component.find("") was for lightning:input but if on my client-side controller I do component.get("") with a lightning:input, I get an error, the page doesn't load itself.

I read the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_find_by_id.htm) but I don't understand.

This is my example:

```
lightning:input aura:id="salutationTest" label="Hello" name="hello" value="hello"
console.log(component.get("salutationTest"));
```

The page doesn't load itself and I have no error message.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171231/component-find-vs-auraattribute

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference and I guess why the page doesn't load itself, it is because I use the `datatabet` component. I don't know if it is normal?