# Get component value directly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bestpractice

This is a general question aimed at finding best approach to do some task. Now I interested in how should I get values from inputs in lightning components. Let's say I have a component:

Example.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="ExampleController">
  <aura:attribute name="exampleDatetime" type="DateTime" access="private" />
  <aura:attribute name="isVisible" type="Boolean" default="false" access="private" />

  <aura:if isTrue="{! v.isVisible }">
    <lightning:input
      type="datetime"
      aura:id="exampleDatetimeInput"
      name="exampleDatetimeInput"
      label="Example Datetime Input"
      value="{! v.exampleDatetime }"
    />
  </aura:if>

  <lightning:button label="Example" onclick="{! c.onClick }" />
  <lightning:button label="Show Input" onclick="{! c.onClickShowInput }" />
</aura:component>
```

ExampleController.js

```
({
    onClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        const action = component.get("c.exmapleServerAction");
        const data = component.get("v.exampleDatetime");
        // OR
        // const data = component.find("exampleDatetimeInput").get("v.value");
        action.setParam("exmapleServerDataParam", data);

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            // skipped for brevity
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    onClickShowInput: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Toggle visibility
        const isVisible = component.get("v.isVisible");
        component.set("v.isVisible", !isVisible);
    }
})
```

Should I event create this `exampleDatetime` attribute at all if the only thing I need is actual value provided by user in the input field? This attribute seems redundant so I feel it can be removed, but I am not sure if this is a good practice to access component's value directly though?

Comment: So you want to know which is better between `component.get("v.exampleDatetime");` and `component.find("exampleDatetimeInput").get("v.value");` ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171231/component-find-vs-auraattribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda depends what you wanna do and how you doing it.

There can't be 2 aura attributes with the same name so `component.get();` will always return a unique individual instance/value.

But more than 1 component can have same `aura:id` (in iterator or loop)  , so component.find() can return an individual component or a list you can iterate over.

That being said, as component.find() returns the component, you can access attributes which you not defined in markup.

**eg** in your case you can get label , validity of ligthning:input
`component.find("exampleDatetimeInput").get('v.validity);`

And even call **aura:method** of that component(Standard or custom)

`component.find("exampleDatetimeInput").showHelpMessageIfInvalid();`

So in broader expect, component.find() can do everything that component.get() can.

src: [component.find() vs aura:attribute](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171231/component-find-vs-auraattribute)

Comment: That's a good explanation of how these access methods differ. I'd also want to understand which is appropriate in a general case. E.g. what is the reason to create attributes in parent controller that hold values of the child components, if you can access component value directly by `component.find("exampleDatetimeInput").get("v.value");`. This would be less markup and code in controller.

Comment: What if you want to pass the attribute from parent component to child component and then show it in child component? in that case you have to use attribute, It genuinly depends on the use case. As updating that attribute will auto-update value in parent.